# Get an NullReference Exception in below code

Tags: c#

```
public class SelectedItems
{
    public Item item;
    public int quantity;
    public double subtotal = 0.0;

}

...

Console.Write("Enter the purchased item count :");
int count = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

while (count > 0)
{  
    SelectedItems itm = new SelectedItems();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the code :");
    itm.item = searchItem(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the quantity :");
    itm.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
    itm.subtotal = itm.item.unitprice * (Convert.ToDouble(itm.quantity));
}
```

The exception occurs in last line.

Comment: What does searchItem(int) do? Any chance it returns a null Item?

Comment: Searchitem() is not returning an instance of item. Post the searchitem() code.

Comment: @Julian thanx for the edit,now makes the question clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `searchItem` is returning a null value.  You need to either change it and have it throw an exception or do a null check before using the return value.

Or better yet, use Code Contracts to assert that it will never return a null value.

Comment: yes!! it didin't return anything it just displayed the item.thankyou

Answer (score 4):

The most likely scenario is that your search by code is failing and returning null.  You should check for this explicitly.

```
while (itm.item == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the code :");
    itm.item = searchItem(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
    if (itm.item == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Item not found. Try again.");
    }
}
```

Some additional notes:

1. Normally public fields are frowned on.  If they need to be public, it's better to make them properties in case you want to change the implementation later.
2. I think the `SelectedItems` class should calculate it's own subtotal rather than having it set externally.
3. When you're dealing with money, you should either be using a custom `Money` class or, at least, `decimal` values rather than double.  Using `decimal`, because it's fixed point arithmetic is typically better than using a `double` (or `float`) so that you're not dealing with fractional cents.

Example:

```
public class SelectedItems
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Subtotal
    {
        get
        {
            if (Item == null)
            {
                return 0m;
            }
            return Item.UnitPrice * Quantity; /* unit price should be decimal */
        }
    }
}
```

You'd probably also want to add some validation or business rule checking, for example, the quantity must be 0 or greater.

Comment: really clean and simple answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `searchItem` method returns `null` if the item is not found. You can check that situation and ask for the code again.

```
while (count > 0)
{  
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the code :");
    Item item = searchItem(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

    if(item == null){
         // Item not found
         Console.WriteLine("Item not found!");
    }else{
         // Item found
         SelectedItems itm = new SelectedItems();
         itm.item = item;

         Console.WriteLine("Enter the quantity :");
         itm.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
         itm.subtotal = itm.item.unitprice * (Convert.ToDouble(itm.quantity));

         count--; // update count if success
    }
}
```

Remember to update `count` if the item is found.

Comment: _thanks again there was a error in search Item, where it didn't return the value_